# How to detect touch inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with four `UIImageView` inside it. I want to detect touch on these imageViews and notify my `ViewController` (which is containing the `UITableView`) which `ImageView` inside which cell has been tapped. How may I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use 4 Buttons instead...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple variants to hit the target. In fact it doesn't matter at all how you are doing it at the cell's level. It may be buttons, image view with tap gesture recognizers or custom drawing and proceeding touch events. I will not provide you with code now as you have a lot of code already given and may find a lot more by little search, thought it may be provided by demand. The real "problem" is in transporting message to the controller. For that purpose I've found only two reasonable solutions. First is the notifications and second is the delegations. Note that the notifications method may lead to visible lag between tap and actual event occurrence as sometimes notifications are brought to objects with little delay...
Hope that it helps.

Comment: I have finally implemented it using UIButtons instead of UIImageView (UIImageView would work, but I've to add gesture recognizers to it, UIButton is a cleaner solution) and adding delegates method to UITableViewCell which notifies the View Controller when and which button has been pressed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
-(void)createGestureRecognizers {

  for(/*each of the UIImageViews*/) {
      UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]

      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

      singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

      [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

      imageView.tag = i;

      [singleFingerTap release];
  }

}


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;//this should be your image view

}
```

Comment: Great solution, but it didn't work for me before I added imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; thanks @Valentin Radu

Answer (score 1):

Use four buttons and set them with different tag values.  Then just check the tag value to see which one was pressed.